# Is there a way to disable all functionality on the lock screen?

Tags: lock-screens, 5.1-lollipop, vanilla-android, nexus-6

I have a Nexus 6, and have noticed that even on the lock screen, there are still things you can do besides enter the passcode.

You can turn the wifi/bluetooth and airplane mode on/off, use the torch, use the camera, turn the phone off.

I don't want to be able to do any of this. The only functionality I want on the lock screen is to be able to enter the passcode to unlock.

In the instance my phone is stolen, I want my phone to remain on, and online, for as long as possible.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: 5.1.1, added a tag